# Dell OMSA connection error on Windows server

Tags: dell-openmanage

I am having connection errors logging in to OMSA Version 9.3 on a Windows Server 2016 Essentials virtual machine running in ESXi 6.0. I have been using OSMA successfully for the past 2 years. About a month ago I started getting:

> Login failed...
>
> Connection error

I have a post in the Dell support forum but the Dell person there just basically tells me to uninstall and reinstall. I have done this through various methods multiple times. I end up with the same results. I HAVE learned something useful though. There are three services that should be installed by the software:

DSM SA Connection Service

DSM SA Data Manager

DSM SA Event Manager

Only one of the three show up in services on the Windows Server:

DSM SA Connection Service

I have tried the troubleshooting guide on page 71 of [this document](https://topics-cdn.dell.com/pdf/openmanage-server-administrator-v93_users-guide3_en-us.pdf). I get the same results, only one service shows in the list. The guide does not specify what to do if any of the services do not show up/don't get installed in services list.

I have not been successful in finding any kind of installation log to see if the services fail to be installed. I assume that because they do not show up in the services list they are not installed.

I have tried Google but none of the solutions I found there worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

** Edit **
I also uninstalled version 9.3 and installed version 8.5. I get the same problem. When I checked the services only one of the three needed services are listed. The problem seems to be that all the services are not being installed.

Comment: `I have a post in the Dell support forum but the Dell person there just basically tells me to uninstall and reinstall` - Have you done that? If not, do so.

Comment: @joeqwerty - Yes, multiple times. I get the same results. I'll edit my question to reflect that.